# SQL define with prefix and suffix

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling, in our DWH I'm trying to automate a proces for generating views instead of manual actions all the time. Here is simple version of what i'm trying to do in a Oracle Database:

```
define SLobject = 'ObjectTest'

select * from '&&SLobject_Src'; -- This one doens't work becauce '_Src' is included but this needs to be excluded.

select * from 'MV_&&SLobject'; -- This works since its a prefix before the '&&' characters.
```

Comment: Please tag RDBMS that you use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Adjusted the post: it is an Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a dot ('.') after the name like this:

```
select * from &&SLobject._Src;
```

and remove the quotes (if using as an object name)